# How can I predict a dependent variable at the regressors' sample means?

Tags: stata, quantile-regression

I am working with several kinds of regressions in Stata (probit, logit, quantile regression,...) I would like to know how to predict the dependent variable at the regressors' sample means. This is straightforward for OLS, but don´t see how to get it for a quantile regression.

Comment: `help qreg_postestimation` is your friend.

Comment: If you found the answer below helpful, then please consider accepting it by clicking on the check-mark.

Answer (score 1):

The `margins` command is useful for this:

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. qreg price weight length i.foreign, nolog

Median regression                                   Number of obs =         74
  Raw sum of deviations  71102.5 (about 4934)
  Min sum of deviations 54411.29                    Pseudo R2     =     0.2347

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |   3.933588   1.328718     2.96   0.004     1.283543    6.583632
      length |  -41.25191   45.46469    -0.91   0.367    -131.9284    49.42456
             |
     foreign |
    Foreign  |   3377.771   885.4198     3.81   0.000     1611.857    5143.685
       _cons |   344.6489   5182.394     0.07   0.947     -9991.31    10680.61
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins, at((mean) _continuous (base) _factor)
Warning: cannot perform check for estimable functions.

Adjusted predictions                            Number of obs     =         74
Model VCE    : IID

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
at           : weight          =    3019.459 (mean)
               length          =    187.9324 (mean)
               foreign         =           0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   4469.386   418.7774    10.67   0.000     3648.597    5290.175
```

This predicts the median at means of the covariates for continuous variables and the base for the dummies (so you can avoid nonsensical values like fractionally pregnant).